# SQL ADD VALUES USING IFELSE AND RANGES

Tags: sql, if-statement

```
TABLE1
STUDENT TIME_STAMP  SCORE   TRIMESTERDATES
1   11/30/2021  4   NA
1   10/2/2021   3   NA
1   4/11/2021   4   NA
2   1/24/2021   2   NA
2   3/18/2021   2   NA
2   2/1/2020    8   NA
3   5/2/2021    10  NA
3   2/10/2021   10  NA
4   7/10/2020   1   NA
4   8/4/2020    3   NA
4   7/13/2020   2   NA
4   5/28/2020   4   NA
4   4/1/2020    4   NA
4   7/1/2021    5   NA
NA  NA  NA  2020-01-01
NA  NA  NA  2020-05-31
NA  NA  NA  2020-08-30
NA  NA  NA  2020-12-31
NA  NA  NA  2021-01-01
NA  NA  NA  2021-05-31
NA  NA  NA  2021-08-30
NA  NA  NA  2021-12-31
```

I wish to add up the SCORE values for each STUDENT across the TRIMESTERDATES ranges to get a table such as this

```
TABLE2
STUDENT SCORE   TIMES
1   …   2020-01-01--2020-05-31
1   …   2020-05-31--2020-08-30
1   …   2020-08-30--2020-12-31
1   …   2020-12-31--2021-01-01
1   …   2021-01-01--2021-05-31
1   …   2021-05-31--2021-08-30
1   …   2021-08-30--2021-12-31
2   …   2020-01-01--2020-05-31
2   …   2020-05-31--2020-08-30
2   …   2020-08-30--2020-12-31
2   …   2020-12-31--2021-01-01
2   …   2021-01-01--2021-05-31
2   …   2021-05-31--2021-08-30
2   …   2021-08-30--2021-12-31
3   …   2020-01-01--2020-05-31
3   …   2020-05-31--2020-08-30
3   …   2020-08-30--2020-12-31
3   …   2020-12-31--2021-01-01
3   …   2021-01-01--2021-05-31
3   …   2021-05-31--2021-08-30
3   …   2021-08-30--2021-12-31
4   …   2020-01-01--2020-05-31
4   …   2020-05-31--2020-08-30
4   …   2020-08-30--2020-12-31
4   …   2020-12-31--2021-01-01
4   …   2021-01-01--2021-05-31
4   …   2021-05-31--2021-08-30
4   …   2021-08-30--2021-12-31
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL has no if statements.

Comment: @jarlh then it can be a 'between' statement ?

Comment: There's a `between` _predicate_, and `case` _expression_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer you wanted from the other question applied to this info.

```
with t2 as (
            select TRIMESTERDATES                                                                                   as semester_start
                  ,coalesce(lead(TRIMESTERDATES) over(order by TRIMESTERDATES), dateadd(year, 1, TRIMESTERDATES))   as semester_end
                  ,row_number() over(order by TRIMESTERDATES)                                                       as semester_id  
            from   t
            where  TRIMESTERDATES is not null
           )
select      student
           ,sum(score)  as total_score
           ,semester_start
           ,semester_end
from        t join t2 on t.time_stamp between semester_start and semester_end
group by    student, semester_id, semester_start, semester_end
order by    1
```

| student | total_score | semester_start | semester_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-05-31 |
| 1 | 7 | 2021-08-30 | 2021-12-31 |
| 2 | 8 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-05-31 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-05-31 |
| 3 | 20 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-05-31 |
| 4 | 8 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-05-31 |
| 4 | 6 | 2020-05-31 | 2020-08-30 |
| 4 | 5 | 2021-05-31 | 2021-08-30 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kwBZYOhU)

Comment: to clarify: I only have TABLE1 and wish to create TABLE2

Comment: @bvowe it is `SELECT .... INTO table2 FROM table1 JOIN .. ` then. Search for "SELECT INTO"

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh you're right. I didn't have concat before. I'll fix it.

Comment: @DannySlor the TABLE1 in Fiddle is different from what I present here

Comment: @bvowe I'll fix it right now

Comment: @DannySlor Msg 208 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
Invalid object name 't2'.

Comment: @bvowe typo. see updated answer.

Comment: @bvowe do you still want every two semesters together or do you want the results per semester?

Comment: @DannySLor per semester!!!!

Comment: @bvowe easy, see updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248450/discussion-between-dannyslor-and-bvowe).

Comment: @DannySlor are you able to address this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901883/sql-aggregate-over-range-of-values