# SQL Aggregate Over Range of Values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have T1 which is formatted as

```
STUDENT SCORE   DATE
1   6   2022-02-01
1   0   2022-03-12
1   5   2022-04-30
1   1   2022-04-30
1   1   2022-05-14
1   1   2022-05-19
1   8   2022-05-26
2   9   2022-01-02
2   10  2022-04-11
2   2   2022-04-12
2   0   2022-04-17
2   7   2022-05-08
2   4   2022-05-12
3   10  2022-01-09
3   2   2022-02-11
3   6   2022-03-16
3   3   2022-03-18
3   2   2022-04-02
3   9   2022-04-27
4   4   2022-02-24
4   0   2022-02-26
4   9   2022-02-28
4   2   2022-03-27
4   8   2022-04-02
4   4   2022-04-14
5   3   2022-01-28
5   5   2022-02-12
5   6   2022-02-18
5   0   2022-02-21
5   4   2022-04-05
XX  0.711094564 2022-02-28
XX  0.60584994  2022-03-31
XX  0.087965016 2022-04-30
YY  0.497937992 2022-02-28
YY  0.727796963 2022-03-31
YY  0.974471085 2022-04-30
YY  0.780187398 2022-05-30
```

First I wish to extract the UNIQUE values of DATE when STUDENT equals to XX and YY. There are some duplicates. These are the trimester ending dates.

Then I wish to SUM up the SCORE values for each STUDENT across the date ranges from Step 1:

[image]

And together I wish to generate this table T2

```
STUDENT SCORE   DATE.START  DATE.END
1   6   2022-01-01  2022-02-28
1   0   2022-03-01  2022-03-31
1   6   2022-04-01  2022-04-30
1   10  2022-05-01  2022-05-30
2   9   2022-01-01  2022-02-28
2   NA  2022-03-01  2022-03-31
2   12  2022-04-01  2022-04-30
2   11  2022-05-01  2022-05-30
3   12  2022-01-01  2022-02-28
3   9   2022-03-01  2022-03-31
3   11  2022-04-01  2022-04-30
3   NA  2022-05-01  2022-05-30
4   13  2022-01-01  2022-02-28
4   2   2022-03-01  2022-03-31
4   12  2022-04-01  2022-04-30
4   NA  2022-05-01  2022-05-30
5   14  2022-01-01  2022-02-28
5   NA  2022-03-01  2022-03-31
5   4   2022-04-01  2022-04-30
5   NA  2022-05-01  2022-05-30
```

And I try this,

```
WITH T2 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE),
COALESCE(LEAD(DATE) OVER(ORDER BY DATE) AS DATE.START,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS DATE.END
FROM T1 WHERE (STUDENT = 'XX' OR STUDENT = 'YY')
)
SELECT STUDENT, SUM(SCORE), DATE.START, DATE.END
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.DATE.START BETWEEN DATE.START AND DATE.END
```

Comment: I don't think you've explained how the ranges work. 2022-01-01 is just going to be a hardcoded value to start? Then each range is from a unique xx/yy date to the next unique xx/yy date? What is the data type for the `date` field?

Comment: @EdmCoff the 2022-01-01 is hard code. The data type is date for the date field

Comment: @EdmCoff I would appreciate very much your guidance I struggle all day on this

Comment: @EdmCoff yes the dates--we take unique values and sort, and then hard code start with 2022-01-01.

Comment: I don't think you can use `.` in column aliases unless you put the alias in backticks. It's normally the delimiter between database, table, and column names.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)`?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't return a date, how can you use that as `DATE.END`?

Comment: The question is ill posed. It is not clear what are the "trimesters" starting dates. The example shows one case in which it starts on 2022-01-01 and goes to 2022-02-28 (i.e., two months), and all the others are just one month long. What gives? It can however be resolved like it is shown with a small hack, making February's two months long and all the others only one month long. In fact, a real solution should be capable of being easily modified to accommodate any "trimesters" definition.

Comment: One other problem is with the data types of the columns. Are scores integers or floats? Well, they should be floats to accommodate the entries for 'XX' and 'YY' records. However, the example solution shows some 'NA's in some rows which should be nulls. It is easy to cast everything to char or varchar, and coalesce nulls to 'NA', but again, it should be clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this one we're looking at score by month so we don't really need the bottom half of the information. In fact, it makes it better not to have it cause then we won't be able to save `student` and `score` as int.

```
select    student
         ,sum(score)                              as total_score
         ,max(dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(date, -1))) as "DATE.START"
         ,max(eomonth(date))                      as "DATE.END"
from      t
group  by student, year(date), month(date)
```

| student | total_score | DATE.START | DATE.END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 1 | 6 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-31 |
| 2 | 9 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2 | 12 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 2 | 11 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-31 |
| 3 | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| 3 | 9 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 3 | 11 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 4 | 13 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 4 | 12 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 5 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 5 | 11 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| 5 | 4 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gqjfZr6Y)

Comment: thank you very much. I don't think I explain myself well. This is a simplified example with month formatting the reality is trimester where we have it on our system like 2020-01-01 THROUGH 2020-04-30, 2020-05-01 THROUGH 2020-08-30, 2020-09-01 THROUGH 2020-12-31

Comment: @bvowe how do you want to group the info? by semester?

Comment: there is a image I put in my question; those values from from the DISTINCT values when STUDENT = XX OR STUDENT = YY. In my actual big data they are different dates but if we can do it based on those I can modify in the actual data...does this make sense? So taking the distinct values in T1 where STUDENT = XX OR STUDENT = YY like shown in that picture. I know it is months but this is just simplified example

Comment: @bvowe check out my other answer.

Comment: This solution is almost correct, but it removed the NA lines, when a student does not have a score for a particular period.

Comment: Besides, if you run the query as present, it will include the line where student is 'XX' and 'YY'. Besides, it prints the "february trimester" starting on '2022-02-01' when the presented solution indicates '2022-01-01' for that particular 'trimester'.

Comment: @DannySlor are you available for paid consult?

Comment: @bvowe Yea. Email me at Danny.slor@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

This answer is EXACTLY what the question was asking for, including the hacks to accommodate for the ill-posed specifications. Here it goes...

```
Select Distinct Date From t1 Where Student = 'XX' or Student = 'YY' Order By date

Select t2.STUDENT as STUDENT,
   COALESCE(CAST(Sum(Case When (t1.DATE is null) Then null
                          When (t1.DATE >= t2.di and t1.DATE <= t2.df) Then t1.SCORE
                          Else 0
        End) AS DECIMAL(2,0)), 'NA') as SCORE, 
   di as "Date.START",
   df as "Date.END"
   From (Select STUDENT, di, df 
                From (Select Distinct STUDENT From t1 Where STUDENT <> 'XX' and STUDENT <> 'YY') as ta,
                     (Select Distinct Case When MONTH(t1.DATE) = 2 Then DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(t1.DATE,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(t1.DATE) - 1 DAY), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
                                           Else DATE_SUB(t1.DATE,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(t1.DATE) - 1 DAY)
                                      End as di,
                                       t1.DATE as df
                                  from t1 where STUDENT = 'XX' or STUDENT = 'YY') as tb
         ) as t2
   Left Join t1
         On t2.STUDENT = t1.STUDENT and t1.DATE >= t2.di and t1.DATE <= t2.df 
   Group By t2.STUDENT, t2.df 
   Order By t2.STUDENT, t2.df
```

In case anyone wants to play with the query, here goes a link to a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G9ft9169) page.

Comment: The trick is the "Select Distinct STUDENT..." joined with di and df dates in the subquery, before actually LEFT joining with the scores and aggregating the results. This way, the periods when a student does not have any scores will result in null values and will be coalesced to 'NA'.

Answer (score 0):

Your date ranges are just month boundaries, so you can use ordinary `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT student, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS year_month, SUM(score) AS score
FROM T1
WHERE student IN ('XX', 'YY')
GROUP BY student, year_month
```

Comment: in reality the data is much larger and it goes many years

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: because you format as month but there will be for example 2019-01-01 and 2020-01-01 and 2021-01-01

Comment: I format it as 2019-01, 2020-01, etc. Don't you see `%Y` in the format string?

Comment: I don't think I explain myself well. This is a simplified example with month formatting the reality is trimester where we have it on our system like 2020-01-01 THROUGH 2020-04-30, 2020-05-01 THROUGH 2020-08-30, 2020-09-01 THROUGH 2020-12-31

Comment: I think you help me before; I still am new on SQL and I take English as a third language!

Comment: This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Here we create a calendar divided to trimesters and join it with our table matching each date to the correct trimester in the calendar.

```
DECLARE @Year INT = '2019';
DECLARE @YearCnt INT = 4 ;
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 01, 01)
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, @YearCnt, @StartDate));

;WITH Cal(n) AS
(
SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 4 FROM Cal
WHERE n < DATEDIFF(month, @StartDate, @EndDate)
),
FnlDt(d) AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(month, n, @StartDate) FROM Cal
),
FinalCte AS
(
SELECT
[Date] = CONVERT(DATE,d)

FROM FnlDt
)
select     STUDENT
          ,sum(score) as total_score
          ,semester_start
          ,semester_end
          
from       (
           select   date                                             as semester_start
                   ,lead(dateadd(day, -1, date)) over(order by date) as semester_end
           from     finalCte 
           ) t2 join t on t.date between semester_start and semester_end   
group by   STUDENT, semester_start, semester_end
```

| STUDENT | total_score | semester_start | semester_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-08-31 |
| 2 | 21 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 2 | 11 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-08-31 |
| 3 | 32 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 4 | 27 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 5 | 18 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/egAbKt1D?hide=5)

Comment: This solution makes some lines disappear, because the t2 join removes those lines which do not have a score for a particular student and trimester period. It also removed all the zero scores.

Comment: The answer didn't remove the zero scores. There are none when dividing to trimesters. Also, this is the way he wanted it presented. I could do left join to the calendar, but that's not what he wanted.